# sortByKey is not working on Dstream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, dstream

I am using Transform API of Dstream(Spark Streaming) to sort the data.
I am reading from TCP socket using netcat.
Following the line of code used:
myDStream.transform(rdd=>rdd.sortByKey())

It is unable to find function sortByKey. Could anyone please help what is the issue in this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `netcat` as an input, you're likely to use `socketTextStream` which returns `ReceiverInputDStream[String]`. In that case `transform` will take a function:

```
(RDD[String]) => RDD[U]
```

Only `RDD[(T, U)]`, where `T` has corresponding `Orderign` can be `sortedByKey`. For other `RDD` you can use `sortBy`:

```
myDSTream.transform(rdd => rdd.sortBy(x => x))
```

Comment: I didn't get that I have just started studying spark streaming. Could you please more elaborative?